# Recognizing specified objects via Android camera using TensorFlow

Tags: android, tensorflow

I stuck with the next problem: is it possible to train TensorFlow model to "remember" any new object that is visible from Android device camera and recognize it next time it will be in the camera focus? I've tried to find tutorial and I've read many of them, but they only describe how to recognize object category with pre-trained model. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow does not support on-device training at this point, only inference. So you can't easily update the model in real time.

However, you might try treating the penultimate layer as a embedding space vector and, and then compute distance between frames to see how related they are.

Alternatively if you have an example of a frame with the object and one without you can get then see the delta that signifies when that object has appeared in the frame.

If you have a labeled dataset, you can retrain the graph offline: see https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/. It will use the knowledge already present in the Inception graph to quickly retrain just the top layer to recognize new classes of objects.